# Is there a reason Url.Action("Grid", "List", new { id = "Organisation"}) would return /List/Index/Organisation instead of /List/Grid?id=Organisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm using Razor in a view and need to generate a Url yet its returning /`List/Grid/Organisation` instead of `/List/Grid?id=organisation`

```
var id = Model.EntityName.ToLower();
Url.Action("Index", "List", new { id = id})
```

I'm expecting `List/Index?id=organisation` to be returned yet instead am getting `List/Index/Organisation`. I'm not sure if its a version issue or I am missing something as I'm fairly new to Razor/C#.

EDIT:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Grid", "List", new { id = id})&key=@key&pageNumber=' 
+ pageNo + '&pageSize=' + pageSize 
+ '&searchName=@Model.UniqueID' 
+ query, function (data) 
{
 $("#@Model.UniqueID").tablegrid('loadData', data);
});
```

And the controller

```
public override JsonResult Grid(string id, string key, string searchName, string searchText, string activeTabs, string pages, string filters, string query, string orderBys, string options, string context, int pageSize = 10, int pageNumber = 1)
        {
            return base.Grid(id, key, searchName, searchText, activeTabs, pages, filters, query, orderBys, options, context, pageSize, pageNumber);
        }
```

It's part of a call used to retrieve information from the database and fills a grid. This code is used on other projects yet for some reason on this new project its giving issues

Comment: How do you have it defined in the controller?

Comment: You have `{id}` defined as a part of the route. Therefore it appears as one. If you want `?id=` (why would you want that?), remove the `{id}` part from the route definition.

Comment: Please show us all of your route definitions.

Comment: @mjwills Sorry, I'm unsure on what you want me to show. As I said im faily new to c#/MVC, are you refering to the SettingsProvider?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+where+are+routes+defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "List",
                url: "list/{id}/{action}",
                defaults: new {controller = "List", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

was meant to be

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "List",
                url: "list/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "List", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Thanks to @mjwills who pointed me in the right direction.